# CCACHE and DISTCC support for non-gcc tools?

Tags: embedded, ccache, distcc

We're looking at ways to speed our compilation up for our project that uses Keil, Xtensa, and potentially another non-gcc compiler tool for a 3rd flavor of core in the chip.

I've been searched for "keil ccache" or "cross-compile ccache", but everything (mostly) comes down to gcc and a few very old projects about supported other tool chains in a fork of ccache.

Does anybody know if this is a fools errand or is it so ubiquitous that there's no reason to ask the question?   My google-fu is failing me so I'm just not finding the info I need on what I'd need to do to make it work with non-gcc tools.

FWIW, GCC is out of the question because it doesn't support our custom Xtensa or DSP processor.

In case it isn't clear what I'm asking:  does CCACHE and/or DISTCC support non-gcc toolsets.  If so, is there anything I need to do special or should it 'just work'?

Comment: I'm not asking somebody to recomment anything to me.  I'm asking if CCACHE and/or DISTCC support non-GCC toolsets.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
for distcc: no, but implementable

As far as I know, current distcc implementation does not support DSP compilers like Ceva or TI cl6x. distcc is heavily depending on gcc interface (command line arguments), that are different in those other compilers (unfortunately there is no standard, neither compatibility).

For distcc, it is possible to implement handling of other command line arguments (most probably somewhere here: https://github.com/distcc/distcc/blob/master/src/arg.c).